# Hibernate batch transaction with multiple ManyToMany Relations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, many-to-many, query-performance

I successfully configured Hibernate to use batch query to create/update objects but there is a scenario that isn't working yet.

I've 3 entities:
- Main Entity
- Entity A
- Entity B

Main Entity has ManyToMany relation with both Entity A and Entity B. Main Entity is the owner of the relation:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "MAIN_A", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_UID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "A_UID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<EntityA> entitiesA = new HashSet<>(0);

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "MAIN_B", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_UID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "B_UID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<EntityB> entitiesB = new HashSet<>(0);
```

I wrote a 3 simple test.
First I create some Entity A and Entity B rows in the database (this is in common with all 2 test cases).

**First scenario**:
Create n Main Entity and for each set only the Entity A

**Result**: Only one insert for all the Main Entity and MAIN_A table entries. So in this case the bath insertion is working as expected.

**Second scenario**:
Create n Main Entity and for each set only the Entity B

**Result**: Only one insert for all the Main Entity and MAIN_B table entries. So in this case the bath insertion is working as expected.

**Third scenario**:
Create n Main Entity and for each set both Entity A and the Entity B

**Result**: Only one insert for all the Main Entity and *n* insert for both MAIN A and MAIN_B table entries. In this case the batch insert didn't work. I googled and searched but I couldn't find an answer.

Does anyone know why it isn't working as expected in the third case? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there anything in the configuration that address my requirement?

The code of the 3 scenarios is pretty straightforward:

```
  Set<EntityA> setA;
  Set<EntityB> setB;
  for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {

  MainEntity e = new MainEntity();
  ac.setEntitiesA(setA); //this is commented in the second scenario
  ac.setEntitiesB(setB); // this is commented in the first scenario

  session.save(e);
}
```

**I posted the same qestion in hibernate forum**: [Hibernate Forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044465)

Comment: can you add the code that is used to perform the 3rd scenario?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I just updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are only saving the `MainEntity` (and I assume the EntityA,B added to the sets are new entities).

In my opinion you should add at least this cascade option to each of your uni-directional relationships:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Otherwise you should invoke save on each of the `EntityA`, `EntityB`.

Comment: EntityA and EntityB are saved before ... What I'm observing is that the updates in the relation tables aren't using batch insertion in the third scenario

Comment: I tried anyway to change the cascade type but it didn't make any difference ...

My problem isn't in the creation of EntityA and EntityB in the database.

My problem is about how Hibernate insert data in the relation tables Main_A and Main_B ... in third scenario the batch insert isn't used and Hibernate performs 300 insert queries instead of 1. This isn't happening in Scenario 1 and 2 and I didn't find an explanation yet!